# Plot a forecast line with Gnuplot?

Tags: excel, linux, bash, plot, gnuplot

I've this data :

```
Serv1;2019-10;2561.36
Serv1;2019-11;3292.65
Serv1;2019-12;3077.58
Serv1;2020-01;3369.98
Serv1;2020-02;3134.53
Serv1;2020-03;593.332
```

With excel, I'm able to create an graph with a forecast line on excel like that :

[image]

I'm able to create a graph with gnuplot :
[image]

With this gnuplot script :

```
set title "test"
set terminal png truecolor size 960,720 background rgb "#eff1f0"
set output "/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/test.png"
set grid
set style line 1 \
    linecolor rgb '#0060ad' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 2 \
    pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5

set offsets 0.5,0.5,0,0.5
set datafile separator ";"
set key left


plot "test.txt" using 3:xtic(2) with linespoints linestyle 1
```

But I don't know how to plot a forecast line with Gnuplot...

Could you show me how to do that ?

Comment: Your first step is to find out how Excel does that forecast (hopefully it is not divination, probably a linear regression). Then you will know what you want to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking for a linear fit and extending this linear function, you can try the following below.

**Edit:**

There is no gnuplot function to get the data value of a certain row and column, e.g. like `a = value(row,column)`. You have to use a somehow strange workaround. Basically, you plot your data into a dummy table, but only the first datapoint of the first block of the first dataset (counting starts with 0). Check `help every` and `help index`.

```
set table $Dummy
    plot $Data u (StartDate=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)) index 0 every ::0:0:0:0 w table
unset table
print sprintf("StartDate: %s",strftime(myTimeFmt,StartDate))
```

Result: `StartDate: 01/03/2020`

**Code:**

```
### linear fit and extrapolation
reset session

$Data <<EOD
01/03/2020,100
02/03/2020,150
03/03/2020,125
04/03/2020,150
05/03/2020,175
06/03/2020,200
07/03/2020,220
08/03/2020,150
09/03/2020,175
10/03/2020,125
11/03/2020,150
12/03/2020,200
13/03/2020,210
14/03/2020,230
EOD

set datafile separator comma
myTimeFmt = "%d/%m/%Y"
set format x "%d.%m." time

# put start date into variable StartDate
set table $Dummy
    plot $Data u (StartDate=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)) index 0 every ::0:0:0:0 w table
unset table

EndDate   = strptime("%Y-%m","30/04/2020")
f(x) = a*(x-StartDate)+ b
set fit quiet nolog
fit f(x) $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 via a,b 

set xrange[StartDate:EndDate]
set grid xtics, ytics

plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red" notitle, \
     [StartDate:EndDate] f(x) ti "linear fit with extrapolation"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Edit 2:** (version for gnuplot 4.6)

Modified for gnuplot 4.6. Where I got problems and found out later is the parameter `FIT_LIMIT = 1e-8` which you need to set for fitting timedata.

**Data:** (`Data.dat`)

```
Serv1;2019-10;2561.36
Serv1;2019-11;3292.65
Serv1;2019-12;3077.58
Serv1;2020-01;3369.98
Serv1;2020-02;3134.53
Serv1;2020-03;593.332
```

**Code:**

```
### linear fit and extrapolation, version for gnuplot 4.6
reset

FILE = "Data.dat"
set datafile separator ";"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m"
set format x "%Y\n%m"

# put start date into variable StartDate, dummy plot
plot FILE u (StartDate=timecolumn(2)):0 index 0 every ::0:0:0:0

EndDate = strptime(myTimeFmt,"2020-09")
f(x) = a*(x-StartDate) + b
FIT_LIMIT = 1e-8
fit f(x) FILE u (timecolumn(2)):3 via a,b 

set xrange[StartDate:EndDate]
set grid xtics, ytics
set yrange[0:4000]

plot FILE u (timecolumn(2)):3 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red" notitle, \
      f(x) ti "linear fit with extrapolation"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for your help ! One more thing, there is a solution to ensure that I don't have to put the first date but only the last ? I mean, I would like that gnuplot take itself the first date in my data.txt then I've just to put the last date by myself ?

Comment: yes, there is a way to take the first value automatically, however, it's not obvious. gnuplot has no function, e.g. like `a = value(row,column)`, but there is a workaround. I will adapt the code.

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for the help ! If I want to use an external .csv file, I've just to replace the variable $Data by the full path of my csv ?

Comment: Yes. I would recommend to define a variable at the beginning, e.g. `FILE = 'C:\Test\myData.csv'` and replace all `$Data` by `FILE`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, again.
Last thing, I've change the example of my data, ( Because my example was wrong, I had made mistakes in my post ). If you have any time, could you check what I changed ?

Comment: what's the problem? Well, change the time specifier `myTimeFmt = '%Y-%m'` and `timecolumn(2,myTimeFmt):3` and `set datafile separator ";"` what you've already done.

Comment: It's exactly what I've done, but I've this error 

`set table $Dummy
           ^
"test.txt", line 10: Column number expected`

Comment: For information, I've the Version 4.6 patchlevel 6 of Gnuplot.

Comment: puh, why can't you update to a recent version? Quite a few things have changed since then (2014). I will put a 4.6 Version.   .... ahm no... problems with fitting. I have to check when I have time again...

Comment: Hello, I can't update my gnuplot version because I don't have the authorization. I try your script for the 4.6 version and I've this error :
`Warning: empty x range [6.23203e+08:6.23203e+08], adjusting to [6.16971e+08:6.29435e+08]
Warning: empty y range [0:0], adjusting to [-1:1]
"data.txt", line 14: undefined variable: myTimeFmt
`

Comment: sorry, this line should read: `EndDate = strptime("%Y-%m","2020-09")`. I will correct it.